# Change Lable of fields dynamically in keystone

Tags: mongoose, keystonejs

I would like to change the labels in keystoneJS (0.3.17) in dependency of the input of an field. 'dependsOn' doesn't work. KeystoneJS overwrites fields with the same name and so only the last 'stockValue' line remains.

```
var keystone = require('keystone');
var config = require('../config/config');
var Types = keystone.Field.Types;

var Stock = new keystone.List('Stock', {
  map: { name: 'label' },
  autokey: { path: 'slug', from: 'label country', unique: true },
  defaultSort: '-slug'
});

Stock.add(
      'Stock',
      { label: { type: String, required: true, initial: true }},
      { country: { type: Types.Select, options: config.models.selectCountry, required: true, initial: true }},

      // de
      { stockValue: { label: 'DAX' , type: Types.Number , dependsOn: { country:'de'} }  },

      // // uk
      { stockValue: { label: 'FTSE', type: Types.Number , dependsOn: { country:'en'} } },

      // // fr
      { stockValue: { label: 'CAC 40', type: Types.Number , dependsOn: { country:'fr'} } },

    );
```

Is there any way to change the label of a form field onChange of the select?
Are there Events like onPopulate ? 
I have tried the 'watch' option also, but this seems to work only for saving and for values not for the label.

Any suggests?

Answer (score 0):

The label of a field can't be changed dynamically in the Admin panel. You could possibly alter what it says with some CSS: by specifying the `adminui custom styles` property in `keystone.init` to point to a LESS file, you can alter the CSS (but not JS) of the admin panel.

In the Admin panel, each label has a `for` property that you can target with a CSS attribuet selector (`label[for='replaceme']`). You can use that to change what is displayed in the label (`::after`), though there is no programmatic or dynamic way of doing that.

Comment: Ok, thank You. I will try this, even when I'm not a css expert. 
With a callback it would be easier.